# How can I combine two functions using default value?

Tags: kotlin, pluralize

I would like to combine these two function　but I'm on trouble how to do it. Could anyone help me please?

```
fun String?.pluralize(count: Int): String? {
    return if (count != 1) {
        this + 's'
    } else {
        this
    }
}

fun String?.pluralize(count: Int, plural: String?): String? {
    return if (count != 1) {
        plural ?: this + 's'
    } else {
        this
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result that you want?

Comment: not sure what you are expecting but `plural: String? = null ` ?

Comment: Also note that your function does not work as you probably expect when input string is null. `null.pluralize(2)` returns `"nulls"` string, but I guess it should return `null`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question. What I'm trying to do is that I would like to combine the two functions. When you use ``.pluralize`` with one parameter, it returns plural form with 's' if the value is not 1. When you add two parameter, it returns like ''person'' to ''people'' if the value is not 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem here is that you have a special requirement for this code and you did not mention this in your question. This is why all answers you get don't work for you. This additional requirement is that you need to use this function not only from Kotlin, but from Java and/or some reflection-based framework. And that changes a lot.

Regular answer to your question is that you need to just use your second function, but declare its parameter as: `plural: String? = null`. This is enough to use it as you expect in Kotlin:

```
"hour".pluralize(2) // hours
"hour".pluralize(2, "foo") // foo
```

But from the Java you will then only see a function receiving 3 parameters:

```
PluralizeExtensionKt.pluralize("hour", 2, null); // hours
PluralizeExtensionKt.pluralize("hour", 2, "foo"); // foo
PluralizeExtensionKt.pluralize("hour", 2); // compile error
```

To fix this problem, you need to additionally annotate this function with `@JvmOverloads`. This will generate two functions in the Java bytecode, so all above examples will work as you expect.

The resulting function looks like this:

```
@JvmOverloads
fun String?.pluralize(count: Int, plural: String? = null): String? {
    return if (count != 1) {
        plural ?: this + 's'
    } else {
        this
    }
}
```

Still, I suggest using an implementation provided in Михаил Нафталь answer. It fixes an additional bug in your code and is more concise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved the problem adding null as default value and  add ```@JvmOverloads``` annotation. It seems like we need that annotation to functions and constructors with default values. Also, the annotation forces it generate multiple overloads. Thank you so much again. This was my first post on Stack overflow and It is amazing to connect with people over the world!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the desired result and handle the `null` case of the input `String` should be the following:

```
fun String?.pluralize(count: Int, plural: String? = null): String? = when {
    count == 1 || this == null -> this
    else -> plural ?: "${this}s"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it gives me build error...```error cannot find symbol```

Comment: Works for me: https://pl.kotl.in/KIVZ26YLg
Are you sure error points on these code lines?

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. I solved the problem adding ```@JvmOverloads ``` annotation with broot's post.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the default value as null in second parameter

```
fun String?.pluralize(count: Int, plural: String?=null): String? {
    return if (count != 1) {
        plural ?: this + 's'
    } else {
       this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. I solved the problem adding ```@JvmOverloads```  annotation with this code.